# How to effectively plot a quantity for 10 variables?

Tags: visualization

This might be a bit of a simple or general question, but I have a case where I have a line plot with 10 lines, graphing a value over time for 10 states. This is too many, making the graph look cluttered - but using the average hides important details about individual lines, and showing only a few lines risks cherry-picking. I am looking for ideally one chart, and ideas on how to more effectively visualize this data - I'm relatively inexperienced at data visualization, so I was hoping some of you have better input than I on this.

Comment: How about facets for each state?

Comment: @user2974951 Just googled that, that could work - do you know the good practice conventions for facets, i.e. is it generally okay to group multiple plots into each facet (so like, 3-3-4), or should they all be separate?

Comment: If it makes sense to group them (as in they are similar somehow) then sure, could work, otherwise separate.